# What does IP Address quadrants reperesent?

Tags: networking, ip-address

If a IP address is 192.168.112.28 what does each quadrant represent in this IP address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Comment: An IPv4 address is 32 bits, the pieces are simply the bytes in the address written in decimal.

Comment: for reference, its also called an octet.

Answer (score 4):

It is a 32-bit unsigned integer, converted into four 8-bit unsigned integers so that humans can read it more easily. The numbers are represented most-significant-bit-first.

Comment: Which is why you can `ping 3232264220` and it will work (well, if you have a `192.168.112.28` on your network anyway)

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes.. they are 32-bit unsigned integers. but i want to know what exactly those integers represent. ex: 192/11000000 -represents a port or something

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask there. Ports are not part of an IP address, and that example doesn't correspond to anything.

Comment: @frozenhaart Don't try to invent meaning where there is none.

Answer (score -1):

IP address consists of 32 bits, it is represented as 4 octets of numbers from 0-255 instead of binary form. 
For example, the IP address: 192.168.112.28 in binary form is 11000000.10101000.01110000.0011100